# Aromatic Substitution in acidic medium

Tags: electrophilic-substitution

[image]

Find product A.

I tried solving but why isn't the answer this  [image]

The answer is given this[image]

Answer (score 1):

Three parts to this answer:

1. You have two electro-philes, the tertiary carbo-cation formed by protonating the alcohol and breaking off a water molecule and then the bromine.  Looks like you got this part.
2. Assume the two electro-philes attack consecutively.  The methoxy group is more strongly activating and ortho/para directing than the alk-yl group for the second attack.  So the bromine and the newly formed carbon-carbon bond will be meta to each other.
3. The sterically favored positions for each are as shown in the given answer.  The carbo-cation favors the position para to the methoxy group.  The bromine picks the position ortho to the methoxy group that's away from the alk-yl function.

Please excuse my use of hyphens.  Device auto-correct was putting in wrong words and I had to defeat it.

Comment: I think you will also get some bromination in the other position next to the -OMe

Comment: Probably so @waylander, and maybe even the carbo-cation could do the same.  But that position is sterically less favorable and presumably the most favored product is wanted.

Comment: @Oscar_Lanzi  Murphy's Law applies. I suspect that "A" will be a mixture of at least 4 compounds in the real world.

Comment: One of Murphy's Laws is everything in textbooks is much simplified compared with the real world.

Comment: Never was a truer word spoken!

Answer (score -1):

The group $\ce{O-Me}$ is an o/p orientator for the second substitution not meta as you answer

Comment: But i want to know the mechanism

Comment: 1) the attack of $ \ce {H ^+} $ leads to cyclization

2) $ \ce {Br_2, FeBr_3} $ forms the electrophile $ \ce {Br ^+} $ which can a priori be substituted for $ \ce {H} $ in the ortho or para position of the benzene ring except that here the para position is not allowed because of the cycle formed in step 1. Write the Wheland intermediates that form when $ \ce {Br^+} $ arrives on the ring: you will see that the ortho position is favored because the substituent $ \ce {O-Me} $ already in place stabilizes the intermediary.

Comment: For the choice of the 2 possible ortho positions which are favored, one is sterically less favorable